# ReactJS - SetState does not update the state when the state variable is a number

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I have a reset button which sets the state of all input fields(controlled) to initial state. 
This works well with with all numbers except for the following scenario:

If Input is 0040, clicking restore does not reset it to 40.
This may work if it is a string, but is there a way to update it if the state variable is a number.

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
  state = {
    code1: 40,
    code2: 60,
    code3: 70,
  }
  
  handleChange = (e) => {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
  
  handleReset = () => {
    this.setState({
      code1: 40,
      code2: 60,
      code3: 70,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <input 
            type="number" 
            name="code1"
            value={this.state.code1} 
            onChange={this.handleChange} 
            min="0" 
            max="100" 
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input 
            type="number" 
            name="code2"
            value={this.state.code2} 
            onChange={this.handleChange} 
            min="0" 
            max="100" 
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <input 
            type="number" 
            name="code3"
            value={this.state.code3} 
            onChange={this.handleChange} 
            min="0" 
            max="100" 
          />
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root" />
```

Comment: Your snippet seems to work as expected. Set one of the boxes to 0040, click reset, and it is reset to the correct value.

Comment: For the first input field if we enter 0040, it does not work because the reset value is 40.

Comment: Oh you want it to _not_ update if the value is 0040?

Comment: Have tried: `constructor`, `Number(...)`, number type `min. max`,  remove `min, max`, restructure state, not a single one worked

Comment: @UncleDave I would like the input to reset from 0040 -> 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use `toString()` for your `input` `value` rather than storing `String` in state. Try this [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-1r46qy)

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <div>
      <input
        step="1"
        type="number" 
        name="code1"
        value={this.state.code1.toString()} 
        onChange={this.handleChange} 
        min="0" 
        max="100" 
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input 
        type="number" 
        name="code2"
        value={this.state.code2.toString()} 
        onChange={this.handleChange} 
        min="0" 
        max="100" 
      />
    </div>
    <div>
      <input 
        type="number" 
        name="code3"
        value={this.state.code3.toString()} 
        onChange={this.handleChange} 
        min="0" 
        max="100" 
      />
    </div>
    <button onClick={this.handleReset}>Reset</button>
  </div>
)
}
```